# Type of variable specified at run time

Tags: fortran, polymorphism, preprocessor

I'm trying to write a program that requires the type of a variable to be specified at run time by user input. Here is a minimal example where I attempt to do this with derived types, though I use the boolean `is_complex` as a proxy for user input.

```
program add_complex_or_real
    use iso_fortran_env, only: stdout => output_unit
    implicit none

    type, abstract :: number_t
        ! TODO: I would like to define a function e.g. print, 
        ! which prints in a specific format depending on the
        ! extended type
    endtype number_t

    type, extends(number_t) :: real_number_t
        real :: val = 0
    endtype real_number_t

    type, extends(number_t) :: complex_number_t
        complex :: val = cmplx(0,0)
    endtype complex_number_t

    class(number_t), allocatable :: x, y
    logical :: is_complex = .false.

    if (is_complex) then
        allocate(complex_number_t :: x, y)
    else
        allocate(real_number_t :: x, y)
    endif

    ! want to be able to call here something like
    ! class(number_t) z = x + y
    ! call z%print()

contains

end program add_complex_or_real
```

This doesn't work since I can't define `val` in the `number_t` abstract type. I also tried defining two different types using the fypp preprocessor (which I am happy to use) but that didn't work out either. I know I could easily do this with the C preprocessor (`#ifdef IS_COMPLEX`) but then I end up with two binaries (one for real, one for complex) and I would rather not do that. I am also trying to avoid unnecessary code repetition such that I can simply use it in an equation without needing a `select type(x)` and having the same equation twice.

Stackoverflow suggested [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000669/fortran-data-polymorphic) question while I was writing, which is very close. With this I can put `class(*), allocatable :: val` in `number_t` but then must remove `val` from the children types, and it still does not solve the problem with repeated code (in the link, the `Square` function is just the same thing repeated a few times -- is there a way to just do `val**2` without wrapping it in an if statement that checks for the complex flag?).

Comment: Other than the types not being defined in a module, what difficulty do you have implementing print type-bound procedures, or overloading operators?

Comment: are you only looking for real/complex numbers or more complex derived types? if so, you could just use `complex` variables that are a generalization of real numbers. with numbers you don't need to define new types, you can just use type guards like `type is (integer)`